# Sqlite-expo operations are not altering/fetching data from the database

Tags: javascript, database, react-native, sqlite, expo

I'm trying to use SQLite to store some data on my React Native + Expo app. I have created crud-style operations on the database, but when I try to perform any of those operations on the database, I get no errors no modifications and not any data back.

***Database Connection***

```
import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite';

const db = SQLite.openDatabase('./database.db');

export default db;
```

***Database operation 1*** Creating table

```
import db from '../databaseConection';

db.transaction((tx) => {
    tx.executeSql(
        `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table (id TEXT UNIQUE, value TEXT, dataType TEXT);`,
        [],
        (_, { rowsAffected }) => {
            if (rowsAffected > 0) {
                console.log(`DATABASE: Table created.`);
                updateTableValues = true;
            } else console.log(`DATABASE: Table not created: `);
        },
        (_, error) => console.log(error)
    );
});
```

When I perform the code above, the database doesn't throw any errors and doesn't create the table, (yes the table that I am trying to create was not already created).

For testing proposes, I created the table using dbeaver and inserted some data just to try to perform some queries.

***Database operation 2*** Query data

```
db.transaction((tx) => {
        tx.executeSql(
            `SELECT * FROM table;`,
            (_, { rows }) => console.log(rows._array),
            (_, error) => console.log(error)
        );
    });
```

Once again, I get no errors and not one single row in the response. I have make sure that the table exists and has data on it.

What exactly I'm doing wrong? and what would be the correct way to access the database?

I'm usign *expo: 44.0.0* and *expo-sqlite: 10.1.0*

Comment: @forpas no, the actual table has another name, I have replaced the original name with "table" just for this post

Answer (score 0):

try initializing your database in a function so that you can call it later

```js
export function init() {
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    database.transaction((tx) => {
      tx.executeSql(
        `
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table (
            id TEXT UNIQUE,
            value TEXT,
            dataType TEXT
        )
        `, [],
        () => {
          console.log("table created")
          resolve();
        },
        (_, err) => {
          reject(err);
        }
      );
    });
  });

  return promise;
}
```

Then, **in App.js**

```js
  const [isDbInitialized, setIsDbInitialized] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    init()
      .then(setIsDbInitialized(true))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);

  if (!isDbInitialized) {
    return <Text>Loading...</Text>;
  }
  
  return (All your screens in case db is initialized successfully)
```